# Overheating issue after installing 14.04

Tags: overheating

I'm new to the ubuntu and Linux thing. I recently downloaded and booted up ubuntu. I made the switch from Windows Vista to ubuntu, and I really like it. Unfortunately, I started getting an overheating issue. My laptop( HP Probook 4510s with 1Gb RAM Celeron processor) overheats until it shuts down. I won't even be using it, but as long as it's on it gets hot. I cleaned the fan out, but it's still overheating. Could you guys point me in the right direction to diagnose and correct the problem? I'm pretty new to the OS, so I may not know a lot of the things or where to actually look. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check this out,http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html I don't know if your celeron is supported but it's worth a shot.

Comment: also, the intel graphics installer can be downloaded here https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads 1.0.5 is for 14.04

Comment: I use tlp on an HP Pavillion, and that makes the system workable.  Still runs hot, but not hot enough to cook eggs on.

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to the new world of Ubuntu. There are a couple of reasons for your overheating issue.

### One of the reasons is the over usage of CPU.

Refer here for [Solving the overheating of CPU](https://askubuntu.com/a/502015/161455)

---

### The Dual graphics problem issue.

- Verify whether you have hybrid graphics in your laptop. (Something like Nvidia + Intel 4000) or (ATI + intel)
- If you have nvidia + intel, see some open source projects [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) or [Nvidia-Prime](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime). I suggest the `Nvidia-Prime` since it is newer and stable + many benefits (Try googling)
- If you have ATI + Intel, I'm probably not sure (My laptop has nvidia + intel). But do take a look at [Hybrid Graphics Section for ATI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) of ubuntu

**Note** 
Always do some research before you install new stuffs in Ubuntu as you are a newbie. Playing with graphics drivers and installing unsupported software may lead to breaking of Graphics which may lead you to re-install the entire OS again (It happened like 10 times in my case).

Hope this gives you idea for your Over heating issue. All the best. Have a coll time using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

if your laptop has Nvidia chipset, this next lines may help you, I was having heat problems when watching any video through the internet o any local video player, cause the computer was overheating a lot, even with external cooler pads, so I search for many suggestions and finally one solution brought coolness to the coreI7 laptop which actually has a GeForce graphics card within

the link is this...

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html

but you should check it out before do anything, but the resumed process is here...

Install Nvidia-Prime in Ubuntu 13.10 or 14.04

Follow the instructions below only if you know what you're doing and how to revert the changes in case LightDM fails to start, etc.!

Update: the instructions below should work under Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr too.

Note: the nvidia-prime package only supports the proprietary Nvidia drivers and won't work with Nouveau!

If you're using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander or 14.04 Trusty Tahr and want to test the Optimus support in the Nvidia Graphics Drivers 319.12+, here's what you need to do:

Firstly, purge Bumblebee if installed: sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
Also, make sure libvdpau-va-gl1 is not enabled system-wide because it causes Nvidia Settings to crash on start - if it is, either disable it or simply remove the package: sudo apt-get purge libvdpau-va-gl1

Install the proprietary Nvidia drivers and the Nvidia Prime package: sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime

Reboot the system.

That's it, after a reboot, your laptop should be using the Nvidia GPU to render the desktop.