# Ubuntu 14.04 used too much processor after latest updatest

Tags: drivers, ati, updates, overheating

after updating ubuntu 14.04 it uses 25-50% of my processor continuously causing my laptop turnoff automatically by overheating. i have no problem before the updates. graphic driver is not a problem, i installed proprietary driver successfully.

My processor is i5 for laptop so i believe i should not having a problem. 
The main cause of overheating my laptop is Ubuntu latest update. please help us resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue in my laptop. Installing the following solved my issue. Probably you'll also resolve your overheating. 2 things to solve your issue.

---

**Note that while I didn't encounter any issues on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 with intel_pstate enabled and from what I've read, it works for others as well, it might not work properly for you so use it at your own risk and only enable it if you know how to disable it in case something goes wrong!**

---

### **1. Enable Intel P-state:**

1. Type in the terminal `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Find the Line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and modify
   it as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=enable"`
3. Save and exit gedit. Now type `sudo update-grub` in terminal and wait the grub to update
4. Reboot and test

**To test:**
Try running `cpupower frequency-info` and you'll get some output similar to

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.30 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.30 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
    25500 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    25500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

**To change the profile of CPU running** run this: `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave`

Replace `powersave` with `performance` if you require more performance. (There is no performance issue for me. I am in power save mode)

### **2. Install Thermald**

just run the command `sudo apt-get install thermald`

This will start automatically

**Always google the stuffs before you install to know more about it**

Hope this solves your issue. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

run command 'sudo top` in a terminal window and see which process(es) are using up the most CPU percentage. They appear at the top.

Once you know them you may be able to decide whether you want to keep them or uninstall them.