# Ubuntu 14.04.3 overheating problems

Tags: drivers, overheating, msi, intel-cpu

My MSI GT60 0NC desktop is overheating and shuts down even if I'm just browsing and listen to music, it's a new Ubuntu installation no weird programs are running. I have installed the last NVidia driver in 'Additional Drivers'. 
it's not overheating in Windows 10.

```
cpu: intel core i7-3610QM...
VGA: Nvidia Geforce GTX 670 / 3GB GDDR5...
RAM: DDR3 8GB+4GB extra ram.. .
```

hope some one can help....

---

fan speed is not the problem the msi gt60 have an keyboard fan control button that max the fan speed sounds like a jet engine, and right now im using ubuntu to right this post and my computer is blowing really hot hot! air at max fan speed.

think i have to boot back to windows now. NO HEAT PROBLEM IN WINDOWS 10!!!!

this post from Zbunjeni looks promising thx.. [Ubuntu 14.04 used too much processor after latest updatest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501840/ubuntu-14-04-used-too-much-processor-after-latest-updatest/502015#502015)

and this http://www.memtest86.com/ from Anders olsson Thx i maybe try it out

or maybe this guid ?? http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html

The result of (lspci | grep VGA):

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114M [GeForce GTX 670M] (rev a1)

i think it is somting whit the drivers of my intel cpu or the nvidia gpu drivers

Comment: Try to get some info from this post, check if Intel P-state governor is active: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501840/ubuntu-14-04-used-too-much-processor-after-latest-updatest/502015#502015

Comment: Overheating = broken hardware.  Check that your fans are working properly, vents are not blocked, and finally, remove the heatsink, clean, reapply thermal grease, and reattach.

Comment: @psusi not always. It could be a simple fan control issue

Comment: There are programs that may be able to control your fan speed manually. Do a Google search for `fan control Ubuntu` and see if anything works for you.

Comment: How you tried running something like [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/), to remove Windows' vs Ubuntu's HW management from the equation?

Comment: @Zacharee1, yes always... the fans are controlled by hardware, and it is up to the hardware to make sure that fans, heatsinks, and any other mechanisms function properly to prevent overheating, even when software runs the system full tilt.

Comment: @psusi the OS still has control over fan speed in most cases, meaning it could be in issue in that regard

Comment: @Zacharee1, nope, the OS is not normally in control.  For a lot of commonly available hardware, lm-sensors does have drivers that can take control if you wish, but this is a bit of a hack and is certainly not something that is done by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can install lm-sensors (`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`) to check both fan speed and temperature. 
[Here is the documentation](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/lm-sensors)